# Is there anyway to configure the firebase firestore emulator to use the data inside the production database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way I can configure the firestore emulator to start off with the data in my production database. I have a lot of test information in there and want to transition it to the local emulator without having to copy each and every document/collection. My initial thought was that there must be a configuration in the `firebase.json` file but I'm sure what it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature to configure the Firestore emulator to read its initial data from the production database.

What you *can* do is export the data from your production database (through its regular API(, and import it to the emulator (also through its regular API) and after that use the [import and export commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#import_and_export_data) to get the data in and out of the emulator.